# UINavigationabar not hiding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UInavigationBar that is set to hidden in the view did load. When I push a view from the first view the navigation bar appears again which is fine. However when I go back to the first view the navigation bar appears again even though. I don't want the first view to ever have a navigation bar? How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the navigation bar again the the `viewWillDisappear` of the second view, or hide the navigation bar in the `viewWillAppear` of the first view.