# I want to hide the iOS nav bar on particular view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Now I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this as i saw this post earlier [UINavigationabar not hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699455/uinavigationabar-not-hiding) but I just want confirmation so i can prove to my developer there is a way to hide the footer nav buttons on a particular view.

I want to hide the buttons on the home view and use big custom buttons instead - he tells me it isn't possible. Seeking a second opinion here.

THanks!

Comment: Make sure you are writing @Jitendra Deore Answer in ViewWillAppear

Comment: @Douglas Ryan are you getting the solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to Hide Navigation Bar used below line

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

If you want to Show Navigation Bar used below line

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 25):

for Disable NavigationBar particular view in Swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

for Enable NavigationBar particular view in Swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
        {
          self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        }
```

Comment: **Thanks you so much.. this should be accepted answer.. it works perfect for me.**

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Anybody that wants it for `Swift` language the line would be

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

This will hide it on all viewControllers

Comment: setNavigationBarHidden still works, to make it animate: `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`